# Seeking open source or free tool to open 3D Mesh GIS files?

Tags: software-recommendations, 3d, 3d-model, 3d-map, mesh

I'm looking a way to open 3d Terrain Mesh files.

I have four different folders with same 3d content , I'd like to open one of them :

1. Cesium folder (with internal Tile folder, web.config, tileset.json)
2. OBJ folder (obj, obj.mtl and with internal Tile folder)
3. OSGB folder (with internal Tile folder)
4. XPL3 folder (with folders floor, Tile and LODTreeExport.xml)

I'm looking for open source or free tool to open 3d Mesh listed above.

I tried to open each of them in `meshLab` and `BlenderGIS` both don't have options to open these files are listed above, same above `google earth`,`Global Mapper`, `openSCAD`, `QGIS`, `AutoCAD Map3D`, `Sketch Up` and `GRASS`.

I am new to the field of GIS.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Your question seems to be asking four broad questions about how to open four formats.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Sure. Question updated

Answer (score 2):

You can try [meshLab](http://www.meshlab.net), it can open OBJ format files, and it is an open source software.

Also [Blender](https://www.blender.org) can be another option which can import many format files and it is also open source and a very powerful 3D renderer. If you want to use GIS data with blender, you can use [BlenderGIS](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS) with which you can import georeferenced raster data.

Comment: I installed Blender , how to connect BlenderGIS ?

Comment: @Toren In the link above there are instructions on how to install BlenderGIS. currently I am not in front of my computer.